# How to check mobile network connectivity via ADB Android?

Tags: android, adb

i am trying to find if there is network connectivity using mobile network on an android device using ADB commands, 
i have tried the following command:

```
./adb shell settings get global wifi_on
```

which returns 1 or 0 respectively but it only works with WIFI, if i turn off wifi and turn ON mobile data, it returns 0, which is expected, so i'd like to know a similar command to test connectivity with mobile data.
I also tried the following:

```
./adb shell ping www.google.com
```

which actually works, but i'd would like better a similar method like the first option i mentioned. 
Thanks